# '/mnt/c$: No such file or directory' when running Kali with WSL

Tags: linux, kali-linux, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running `/mnt/c$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rapid7/metasploit-omnibus/master/config/templates/metasploit-framework-wrappers/msfupdate.erb > msfinstall && chmod 755 msfinstall && ./msfinstall` on Kali to install metasploit, but when I run it I get this:

```
-bash: /mnt/c$: No such file or directory
```

I added automount to wsl.conf and restarted wsl, but it still isn't working.

Comment: This is very clearly a case of "I use Kali, although I'm not very familiar with Linux", and [Kali themselves say you should know Linux fairly well before starting with Kali](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/).

Comment: @jesse_b Stupid me. I copied to much from the github page.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because : lack of effort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've mistakenly copy/pasted too much of the command to run. The `/mnt/c$` is intended to be the prompt, and shouldn't be entered as part of your command. You'll make more progress running:

```bsh
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rapid7/metasploit-omnibus/master/config/templates/metasploit-framework-wrappers/msfupdate.erb > msfinstall && chmod 755 msfinstall && ./msfinstall
```